# Use Beautifulsoup to turn <ul> <li> and unbounded items into a list

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing, beautifulsoup

I want to take my text below, and assemble it into a list of objects as shown below. I know this can be done with BeautifulSoup.

Starting html text:

```
input_string = "peanut butter1
<ul id="ul0002" list-style="none">peanut butter2
    <li id="ul0002-0001" num="0000">2.0 to 6.0 mg of 17&#x3b2;-estradiol and</li>
    <li id="ul0002-0002" num="0000">0.020 mg of ethinylestradiol;</li>
    <br>
    <li id="ul0002-0003" num="0000">0.25 to 0.30 mg of drospirenone and</li>peanut butter3
</ul>peanut butter4"
```

Desired output:

```
list1 = [
    ['peanut butter1', 'no tag'],
    ['peanut butter2', 'ul'],
    ['2.0 to 6.0 mg of 17&#x3b2;-estradiol and', 'li'],
    ['0.020 mg of ethinylestradiol;', 'li'],
    ['<br>', 'no tag'],
    ['0.25 to 0.30 mg of drospirenone and', 'li'],
    ['peanut butter3', 'no tag'],
    ['peanut butter4', 'no tag'],
]
```

The below does not produce the output I want:

```
x = input_string.findAll()
list1 = []
for y in x:
    list1.append([y.renderContents(), y.name])
```

Comment: Actually, I did read through all the documentation yesterday, and didn't find the answer. Hence I thought the solution could be done with regex. When beautifulsoup was mentioned, I knew I did not know the answer already as I had already failed at it. So I asked this question. I thought the point of SOF was to ask questions like this. If its not, and we are supposed to read through all documentation available and solve all problems, there really is no use for this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is to iterate over `BeautifulSoup` text items and check for the `parent`:

```
from pprint import pprint
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


input_string = """peanut butter1
<ul id="ul0002" list-style="none">peanut butter2
    <li id="ul0002-0001" num="0000">2.0 to 6.0 mg of 17&#x3b2;-estradiol and</li>
    <li id="ul0002-0002" num="0000">0.020 mg of ethinylestradiol;</li>
    <br>
    <li id="ul0002-0003" num="0000">0.25 to 0.30 mg of drospirenone and</li>peanut butter3
</ul>peanut butter4"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(input_string, 'html.parser')

result = []
for item in soup.find_all(text=True):
    value = item.strip()
    if value:
        parent = 'no tag' if item.parent.parent is None else item.parent.name
        result.append([parent, value])

pprint(result)
```

prints:

```
[['no tag', u'peanut butter1'],
 [u'ul', u'peanut butter2'],
 [u'li', u'2.0 to 6.0 mg of 17\u03b2-estradiol and'],
 [u'li', u'0.020 mg of ethinylestradiol;'],
 [u'li', u'0.25 to 0.30 mg of drospirenone and'],
 [u'br', u'peanut butter3'],
 ['no tag', u'peanut butter4']]
```

Hope that helps.